# Is the more you prove abroad income earnings the better you get a tax deduction or it's the opposite?

Tags: germany, taxes, tax-deductions, tunisian-citizens

I worked for 8 months in France (as a contractor) where I get monthly fees (Tax free income based on a Tunisian-French tax treaty) in Euro and my monthly salary in Tunisia.

I was able after consulting the tax consultant to provide all the proof about the money I earned in France because of the online banking facilities, but for the Tunisian income during that year, it would be harder to request my account history for that year and get back those document here in Germany.

Does it really worth to prove how much I earned in Tunisia and would it get me a better tax refund? Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

German tax office wants your world wide income to calculate the rate at which you are taxed for your German income. So you will pay more tax the higher your foreign income. On the other hand, not stating your foreign income would be tax evasion.

On the other hand, you don't need to *prove* your income, you have to make them believe what you say.

(To explain: If you make €20,000 in Germany, and €10,000 elsewhere, they calculate the tax rate in percent that someone with €30,000 income in Germany would pay, and you pay that percentage of €20,000. If you make €20,000 in Germany, and €100,000 elsewhere, they calculate the much higher tax rate in percent that someone with €120,000 income in Germany would pay, and you pay that percentage of €20,000. )